# Click through rate from Google search for a page with video fell drastically when Google put it in a special video section. How can we opt out?

Tags: seo, google, search-results

There is a video on the page, embedded as:

```
<div class="imgContainer" data-videosrc="/medien/videos/video.mp4">
  <img src="/medien/videos/thumb.jpg" alt="" title=""/>
  <a href="javascript:VIDEO.open('12345')"><div class="video"></div></a>
</div>
```

**Note**: no structured data at all!

Since some time Google begun to show this page in SERP as a video, like on screenshot (befor this it was shown as "normal" blue link):

[image]

Since this time the click rate drops disastrously, like at the screenshot:

[image]

**Question**: what would you do to move Google to display the page as blue link again? This click rate drop is pretty painful.

My only idea is to convert the video to a gif or flv - but this seems to be a nuclear overkill...

Comment: I'm surprised the CTR is so low.   Google is pushing structured data so hard so that your site gets special displays like that.   I would have thought they would have tested to make sure they performed well before implementing them.

Comment: that was my reaction too - Google does everything to get the importance of rich media higher, with a background idea, it would positively influence the CTR. But, in this case, on this page are special informations for insurance customers, about new insurance product - and video search result is anything, what customers don't expect to see. But Google thinks the opposite thing about it - and the result is the dropping CTR. In short - Google completely misunderstood the page intention.

Comment: My only thought would be to hide the video from Google.   Load it into the page via JavaScript that is blocked by robots.txt.

Comment: Yes, it ssems to be nearly the single solution...But it is such a good video! Its funny and, running in TV, it has very good conversion rate. But it is not the **main** entity of the page - and Google doesn't understand this...